# Mongoose: $project after $lookup don't show a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two models **user.js** and **schedule.js** and I have a query (aggregate) that i need to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to "join" these models. After the $lookup i'm using a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) that select the fields that i want to show in the result of my query, but the fields `scheduleStart` and `scheduleEnd` don't show in my result.

**User.js (model)**

```
  name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: {
        String
    },
    lastName: {
        String
    },
    storeKey: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
    birthday: String,
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    doc: String,
    email: {
        type: String
    },...
```

**Schedule.js (model)**

```
 service: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    filters: [String]
  },
  info: {
    channel: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'app'
    },
    id: String,
    name: String
  },
  scheduleDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleStart: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleEnd: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
```

**My query**

```
 User.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,     
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          cpf: "$cpf",      
          phone: "$phone",
          email: "$email",
          birthday: "$birthday",
          lastName: "$lastname"      
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: "$services"
        },    
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        localField: "_id.phone",
        foreignField: "customer.phone",
        as: "user_detail"
      }  
    },  
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        name: 1,
        cpf: 1,      
        phone: 1,
        email: 1,
        birthday: 1,
        totalServices: 1,
        totalValue: { "$sum": "$user_detail.value" },
        scheduleStart: 1,
        scheduleEnd: 1,
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }   
  ])...
```

**Result of my query:**

```
count: 1
totalServices: 89
totalValue: 2374
_id:{
birthday: "1964-03-18",
cpf: "319335828",
email: "jdoe@gmail.com.br",
id: "5b1b1dcce1ab2a8eb580f",
name: "Jonh Doe",
phone: "11996370565"
}
```

Comment: `scheduleStart` is the field from `schedules` collection. And your `$lookup` details is inside the `user_details`. So put the `user_details` inside the `$project` stage.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: Try this `{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    name: 1,
    name: 1,
    cpf: 1,      
    phone: 1,
    email: 1,
    birthday: 1,
    totalServices: 1,
    totalValue: { "$sum": "$user_detail.value" },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    user_detail: 1
  }
}`

Comment: can i bring only the `scheduleStart` and `scheduleEnd` inside `user_detail` in that $project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `$project` stage with [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) aggregation

```
{ '$project': {
  '_id': 1,
  'name': 1,
  'cpf': 1,      
  'phone': 1,
  'email': 1,
  'birthday': 1,
  'totalServices': 1,
  'totalValue': { '$sum': '$user_detail.value' },
  'scheduleStart': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$user_detail.scheduleStart', 0] },
  'scheduleEnd': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$user_detail.scheduleEnd', 0] },
  'count': { '$sum': 1 }
}}
```